# woocommerce change continue shopping link in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the link for the "Continue Shopping" button in Wordpress WooCommerce.  I have tried 6 different solutions that I found online, all of which involved editing the functions.php file using the hook woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect.

None work and I have seen a few unanswered posts around the web with the same issue, which leads me to suspect that something has changed in the latest version of WP or WC.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try add below code into your theme functions.php:

```
function custom_woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect( $return_to ) {
  return get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 'my_woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 20);
```